# On-premises users aren't getting email messages from Office 365 users

Tags: exchange-2013, office365, exchange-hybrid

The DNS name of the Exchange 2013 server is servername.abc.local
I setup a Hybrid Environment with the Public domain xyz.nl
The UPN suffix of the abc.local domain is xyz.nl and I updated al users.
The MX record is pointing to the On-Premise Exchange server
Everything works as far a I know except one thing.
On-premises users aren't getting email messages from Office 365 users.
The error message is: "Remote Server returned '550 5.4.310 DNS domain abc.local does not exist.
How to solve this?

Comment: What's the "Generating server" that returned this error message? It would also help if you could add the `Received` headers of the original message attached.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any errors when running HCW?

What is the email address for on-premises users?
And you also could check the settings of the hybrid outbound connector. You could check if it configured to route the message to xyz.nl.